# Zeppelin autocompletion on Mac OS X?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I use Zeppelin (0.7.1) on Chrome (57.0.2987.133) on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). The autocompletion `ctrl + .` does not work.

Does anyone of you have figured out how to use it?

Comment: It would be nice to describe your Zeppelin version, Browser version as well.

Comment: Thanks @1ambda, question updated.

Comment: I get something happening.  crtl + . brings up a menu of local variables.  if I have typed something before it uses the text as a filter in the menu.  however what doesn't work is writing the variable name and then a . and then auto completing the methods and attributes of the objects.  has anyone got this working? this seems to be a big reason to stick with jupyter for me.